# Next JS Script Component Vs normal script tag with async and defer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

What's the difference between next js `<Script />` component rendering strategies (`afterInteracive`, `beforeInteractive`, `lazyLoad`) and using normal `<script />`  tag with `async` and `defer`?

Answer (score 1):

`afterInteractive`, `beforeInteractive` and `lazyLoad` handles script and decide when it's loaded (from [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script#strategy)). It also differ in 'place' where it loads the script. `beforeInteractive` loads your script in `<head>` of your project. `afterInteractive` loads your script in `<body>` of your project.

Basically, it's just Nextjs way to handle scripts in your app. Main difference is that you should not use script tag in head ([in Nextjs](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-script-tags-in-head-component)) but place it anywhere else and use right strategy so Nextjs knows where to place it.